# Regex: Select and delete only the first word at the beginning of each line

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I want to select and delete only the first word at the beginning of each line

For example:

```
My favorite flower is yello.
I love cars.
Book and flowers are my game.
```

The Output should be:

```
favorite flower is yello.
love cars.
and flowers are my game.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\S+\h*(.*$)`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
\S+         # 1 or more non space
\h*         # 0 or more horizontal spaces
(.*$)       # group 1, rest of the line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^([a-z][A-Z]{0}))`
- Replace by: `\2\2`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Find All in Current Document</kbd>

Comment: `[A-Z]{0}` doesn't make sense, and you don't have group #2 so `\2` is empty.

Comment: yes, @Toto but if you test it with notepad++, you will see that my formula is working fine . Of course, your regex is much better. Thanks

Comment: Find: `^[a-zA-Z]` and Replace: `EMPTY` will do exactly the same. But, as your attempt, it will leave a space at the beginning of line.